# How to stop enter key from submitting form when input area in jQuery ui form dialog is highlighted? (sample code)

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery-ui-dialog

See code below for working demo. A jQuery UI modal dialog box is opened, and the user is asked to enter a password. If the `submit` button is highlighted, everything works just fine. If, however, the input area is still highlighted, then the page appears to reload, and the URL in the browser is changed to `example.com?confirm_password=asdfasdf#`.

I suspect this is because I have a form embedded in the dialog box, but this is based on a jQuery example.

How can I fix this so that pressing the enter key with the text input box highlighted is equivalent to clicking on submit?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Problem Demo</title>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myDialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Submit": function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#openMyDialog').click(function() {
                $('#myDialog').dialog('open');          
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="openMyDialog" href="#">Open Dialog</a>
    <div id="myDialog">
        <p style="text-align: left;">Please enter your password.</p> 
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="confirm_password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" value="" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear. I'd like pressing the enter key to be equivalent to clicking on submit. I can just delete the <form> lines, and I get rid of the page loading (but I'm not sure it is valid to have <input> and <label> without a form), but if the focus is on the input box, pressing enter doesn't submit the info. Apologies for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It is look like submit function is only working with button key(button submit function being called only on button click ).

you should explicitly bind your form using

```
$('yourformselector').submit(function(){
          $(this).dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear. This code prevents the user from pressing the enter key when the Submit button is highlighted.

Comment: I made changes in my code. Submit is binded with button only. when you are pressing enter on input it is actually submitting the form.